# L1 B visa status issue

Tags: visas, usa, visa-refusals

I have applied for L1 blanket visa and appeared for the interview on 5th July 2017 at U.S. Consulate General Chennai office.

I have cleared the interview and the visa officer said that my visa is approved and gave me two copies of I-129S (attached) with an approved stamp, and took my passport.

However, when I collected my passport from VFS Ahmedabad dropbox today, attached to it was a blue sheet of paper that says **'Your Blanket L-1 application is not clearly approvable under section 8 CFR 214.2(I)(ii)(D) and INA 101(a)(15)(L).'**

Since the visa officer returned I-129s with an approved stamp, why wasn't my passport also stamped? Do I need to submit any missing documents, or was there an issue with my application?

Comment: The 8 CFR 214.2 reference doesn't seem quite right. My guess, however, is that while they approved your application under the blanket petition they are now questioning your employer's eligibility for the blanket petition in the first place. You need to talk to your employer to find out what happened.